# fetchAll statement to return only some columns

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am developing a web app using zend framework in which I want to enable my users to search from other users using zend fetchAll function. But its returning complete column and I want several values only. Here is my sample code:

```
$query=$table->select('id')->where("name LIKE ?",'%'.$str.'%')->limit(10);
$model=new Application_Model_Users();
$rowset=$model->getDbTable()->fetchAll($query)->toArray();
```

I want to get only name and some other columns. Its returning all columns including password too.:p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$select = $db->select();

$select->from('some_tbl', array('username' => 'name')); // SELECT name AS username FROM some_tbl
$select->from('some_tbl', 'name');                      // SELECT name FROM some_tbl
$select->from('some_tbl', array('name'));               // SELECT name FROM some_tbl

$select->from('some_tbl', '*'); // SELECT * FROM some_tbl
$select->from('some_tbl');      // SELECT * FROM some_tbl

// in case of joins, to disable column selection for a table
$select->from('some_tbl', array());
```

Comment: The columns syntax I posted is easier and clearer when working Zend_Db_Table

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `columns` call to fetch only specific columns. In this case, we request the id and name columns:

```
$columns = array('id', 'name');
$query = $table->select()->columns($columns)->where("name LIKE ?",'%'.$str.'%')->limit(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create the Zend_Db_Select object
$select = $db->select();

// Add a FROM clause
$select->from( ...specify table and columns... )

// Add a WHERE clause
$select->where( ...specify search criteria... )

// Add an ORDER BY clause
$select->order( ...specify sorting criteria... );
```

[Building Select queries - Zend Framework programming documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html)